# AWK: how to remove certain lines that do NOT contain certain pattern?

Tags: awk, wildcards

I have a file that contains lines with various alphanumeric strings that are separated with space-dash-space. However, there are lines where only one alphanumeric value and a separator are present but the other string value is missing. Example:

```
MN_L_DAX-NORDNET_D36 - DK0060975886
MN_L_DAX-NORDNET_D35 - DK0060975613
DK0060056323-DKK -
DK0060186294-DKK -
```

The last two lines in the above sample lack alphanumeric string on the right-hand side of the separator and I want to remove them.
I tried to use the following awk expression:

```
awk '!/* - /' sourcefile.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt sourcefile.txt
```

By `!/* - /` I mean "look for pattern where after any character (*) there is a space-dash-space ( - ) and nothing afterwards, and if no such pattern is found (!)" then move the rest of the lines to temp.txt file and and replace the sourcefile.txt contents with temp.txt contents.
However, when I run the above awk script, nothing happens with neither sourcefile.txt contents - everything remains the same. I get no error either. 
What could be wrong here?
Given the above sample lines the desired output after running awk script should look like this:

```
MN_L_DAX-NORDNET_D36 - DK0060975886
MN_L_DAX-NORDNET_D35 - DK0060975613
```

Comment: Try this `awk '!/^.* - /'` if I understand you correctly, or `awk '!/^.* -$/'` if I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print lines that end in an alphanumeric character is simply:

```
$ awk '/[[:alnum:]]$/' file
MN_L_DAX-NORDNET_D36 - DK0060975886
MN_L_DAX-NORDNET_D35 - DK0060975613
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
awk '$3' inputfile
```

This is shorthand for `awk '$3!=""'`, which is shorthand for `awk '$3!=""{print}'`, which is short for `awk '$3!=""{print $0}'`

For the record:

`sed /-$/d` is probably faster, and `grep -ve '-$'` even faster still.

Comment: Using `$3` as the condition will also evaluate to false if `$3` is numerically equivalent to zero. e.g. this won't print anything: `echo 1 2 000.00000 | awk '$3'`

Comment: @guest The sample input data, and the accepted answer did seem to hint, that '00.000' or any similar zero-ish value would not be expected valid content for $3. I had debated with myself, whether I should write `'$3'` checks, if $3 looks "truthy-ish", but then did not want to explain that .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @guillermo chamorro suggestion I was able to achieve the desired output by modifying my script in the following way:

```
awk '!/^.* -$/' sourcefile.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt sourcefile.txt
```

Thank you Guillermo.

Comment: The `^.* ` part of your regexp is doing nothing useful.